# Spring not correctly decoding UTF-8 in POST on glassfish server

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp, glassfish

I am running Spring framework on Glassfish V2.
I want to save Punjabi words in mysql database. For this I have tried following approach
Firstly I have included this in my jsp page:-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java"%>
```

Then also tried by adding  `acceptCharset="UTF-8"` attribute in jsp form tag:-

Also included encodingFilter filer in web.xml as a first filter

```
<filter>
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

I have also tried by adding `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />`
in glassfish-web.xml

After trying all this, my values are still going into db in ???? format.
Moreover if I directly insert values in db from backend then values are going in correct format.

Please help...

Comment: Backend means using insert query from DB tool

Comment: At debugging values are appearing like u0a39\u0a3e\u0a02

Comment: I am using URL as jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?requireSSL=false&useUnicode=true&char acterEncoding=UTF-8